# Delay for change from overflow:display to overflow:hidden to take effect in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, transform

I have a div containing a bunch of elements that I don't want to leak out, but one of those elements is an image (with the same width as the parent div) that I want to enlarge on hover. But when I change overflow:hidden to visible on hover, it behaves really weirdly in Chrome.

HTML:

```
<div class="ruiner">
    <img src="wwwwwww">           
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ruiner {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.ruiner:hover {
    overflow:visible
}

img:hover{
    transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
}
```

Please check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/herrkarlson/LzAju/) out to see what I mean.

Is there anyone who knows how to make this work in Chrome?

Comment: You others are getting seeing it, right? Or is there something wrong with my chrome?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *weird* behavior mate. Can you explain in some words?

Comment: I see some rendering artefacts left behind when the image scales back to normal

Comment: Yes, it's like the overflowing parts of the image (especially left, top and bottom side) still thinks they should transformed even after the mouse leaves. One to two seconds later, they turn back into the white pixels they're supposed to be. It looks like [this](http://imgur.com/GZc0Q16).